# How can I add space between the strings which are multiplied?

Tags: python, string

This is how my code looks like:

```
shopping=["Bread","Butter","Juice"]
for products in shopping:
    print(products * 3 + " ")
```

Its output is:

**BreadBreadBread 
ButterButterButter
JuiceJuiceJuice**

I want my output to be:

**Bread Bread Bread
Butter Butter Butter
Juice Juice Juice**

Comment: That seems rather basic, what have you tried?

Comment: I would try:
````print( ( products + " ") + * 3) ```` or a for loop around it. 
with 3 times ````for x in range(3):
    print(products + " ")````

Answer (score 3):

Try this (Not the best way but wanted to show how it can be done by your way):

```
shopping=["Bread","Butter","Juice"]
for products in shopping:
    print((products + " ")* 2 + products)
```

If you want to form a list, then using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and `format`:

```
print(["{0} {0} {0}".format(i) for i in shopping])
```

Outputs:

```
['Bread Bread Bread', 'Butter Butter Butter', 'Juice Juice Juice']
```

**Or**

```
shopping=["Bread","Butter","Juice"]
for products in shopping:
    print("{0} {0} {0}".format(products))
```

Outputs:

```
Bread Bread Bread
Butter Butter Butter
Juice Juice Juice
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use multiplication (though available, it's rarely needed). Instead, use `' '.join`:

```
print(' '.join([products for _ in range(3)]))
```

You could use *list* multiplication in the above, as you are not concerned about the nature of the resulting list, beyond it being iterable.

```
print(' '.join([products] * 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

More simply:

```
shopping=["Bread","Butter","Juice"]
for products in shopping:
    print(products + " ") * 3
```

Output:

```
Bread Bread Bread 
Butter Butter Butter 
Juice Juice Juice
```

Comment: This code shows the error " unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int' "

Comment: I tried with this tool online: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php